# Hide JUnit's stack trace when testing by creating a "new Exception()" that isn't thrown?

Tags: java, junit

I am testing one of my methods w/ JUnit and the method takes an `Exception` as a parameter.  The test looks roughly like this:

```
public void testSomething() {
...
  callMethod(param1, new Exception("ignore exception"));
}
```

When I do this, the act of creating an Exception (not throwing it) dumps this to System.err

> java.lang.Exception: ignore exception
>       at ...testSomething
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141

Is there any way to suppress this output?
I Goggled for everything I could think of, but it picks up all sorts of unrelated stuff.

Comment: I suspect that it's actually something inside `callMethod` that is dumping the `Exception` to `System.err`. Constructing an `Exception` object on its own does not cause this to happen.

Comment: @AdamPaynter: how do you construction an Exception object on it's own?  AFAIK, that's what I'm doing above w/ the "new Exception"...

Comment: You're right, you are constructing an `Exception` object on it's own. All I was trying to say was that it's probably not the `Exception` constructor that is writing to `System.err`. Rather, once that `Exception` is constructed, it's probably something inside `callMethod` that dumps the constructed exception.

Comment: Agh..you're right.  I had some test code that did "ex.printStackTrace();" that I forgot to take out.
That was stupid. :-P

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the function call did an ex.printStackTrace() debug statement in it that I forgot to take out so Adam was correct.

Answer (score -1):

Can you derive a class from Exception without calling the parent constructor?

Comment: No; you cannot instantiate a derived class without calling the base constructor.

Comment: Really?  Did you compile and run a test before downvoting that?  Because I did after you downvoted it.

Comment: Of course, what you may have meant is that a default constructor will be called explicitly, which may be correct (but I haven't tried it).

Comment: You mean _implicitly_.  And, yes.  A constructor will **always** be called.